# How to edit the quantity box in my shopping cart using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been created small shopping cart page using php and mysql.

All the products are stored in database. Now my page look like this http://s13.postimg.org/fsapl50hj/Untitled_1_copy.png.

Top of the page, in quantity box. I need to edit the box, because if customer want change(increase or decrease) the quantity after add to cart,

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");
            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Simple PHP Shopping Cart</TITLE>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="shopping-cart">
<div class="txt-heading">Shopping Cart <a id="btnEmpty" href="index.php?action=empty">Empty Cart</a></div>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    $item_total = 0;
?>  
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Code</strong></th>
<th><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th><strong>Price</strong></th>
<th><strong>Action</strong></th>
</tr>   
<?php       
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></strong></td>
                <td><?php echo $item["code"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?></td>
                <td align=right><?php echo "$".$item["price"]; ?></td>
                <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=<?php echo $item["code"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction">Remove Item</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
        $item_total += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
        }
        ?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align=right><strong>Total:</strong> <?php echo "$".$item_total; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>    

  <?php
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need to use another form with an input box that retrieve the quantity from user, Html5 has a input type number ( user can only add number ):
`<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="50" value="<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>">`

 - but it's for html5
for Xhtml & HTML4.01 you can use:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?>" name="quantity">
```

& you also need a simple number validation by php using "is_numeric" function.

Hope i can help